# Get All Refunds in BigCommerce

Tags: rest, bigcommerce

I'm using BigCommerce and want to know if there is an endpoint that retrieves all refunds. I've seen the v3 orders endpoint `/orders/{order_id}/payment_actions/refunds`, but this gets all refunds for a specific order.

I want to know if its possible to get all refunds of all orders.

Edit:

Found the path for refunds, but now I need to know if I can use query params to filter the data or not.

In the orders API we can use filters like `min_date_modified`. Can I use the same for the refunds endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems they've missed the documentation on that endpoint, but if I was to guess I'd try `/v3/orders/payment_actions/refunds?created:min=2021-01-01T23:05:05%2B00:00` since that's how other V3 endpoints work. I used that query and it didn't error (once I encoded the + sign in the time), but I don't have production creds at hand to test with real refunds.

Comment: Thanks! This really helped, I'll look through the docs so I can use a date-modified or id filter

Answer (score 1):

I found an article that specified the endpoint URL

https://medium.com/bigcommerce-developer-blog/order-refund-api-automate-refunds-in-bigcommerce-7a00aaa6fae7

the endpoint to get all refunds is `orders/payment_actions/refunds`